# Error importing csv dates into a mysql server

Tags: mysql, csv, datetime

The following code doesn't work on the part of importing dates and i cant figure why. Dates in the csv are like DD/MM/YYYY and the error is it imports all the data but leaves null every date. Also error says:
ER_UNKNOWN_SYSTEM_VARIABLE: Unknown system variable 'FECHA_POSICION'

Lines in the csv file look like:
EDC00001,66600/7089855,21/01/2021,21/01/2021,"DEPOSIT Deposit",4000,4000
EDC00002,66600/7089855,29/01/2021,29/01/2021,CFDs,"-9,94","3990,06"

```
USE DATA_BASE;
CREATE TABLE ESTADO_DE_CUENTA (
ID_OPERACION VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ID_CUENTA VARCHAR(20),
FECHA_POSICION DATE,
FECHA_VALOR DATE,
CONCEPTO VARCHAR(100),
IMPORTE FLOAT(12, 2),
SALDO_EN_EFECTIVO FLOAT(12, 2)
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'PATH.csv' INTO TABLE ESTADO_DE_CUENTA2 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(ID_OPERACION, ID_CUENTA, @FECHA_POSICION, @FECHA_VALOR, CONCEPTO, IMPORTE, 
SALDO_EN_EFECTIVO) 
SET FECHA_POSICION = STR_TO_DATE(@FECHA_POSICION, '%d/%m/%Y') 
SET FECHA_VALOR = STR_TO_DATE(@FECHA_VALOR, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to show us some lines of your CSV file.  And, please explain what actually goes wrong. *Doesn't work* could mean anything from "incorrect dates were stored in the table" to "the server caught fire and the data center burned down." :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can call SEt only once and all columsn have to be separated by comma

Like

```
USE DATA_BASE;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'PATH.csv' INTO TABLE ESTADO_DE_CUENTA2 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(ID_OPERACION, ID_CUENTA, @FECHA_POSICION, @FECHA_VALOR, CONCEPTO, IMPORTE, 
SALDO_EN_EFECTIVO) 
SET `FECHA_POSICION` = STR_TO_DATE(@FECHA_POSICION, '%d/%m/%Y') , `FECHA_VALOR` = STR_TO_DATE(@FECHA_VALOR, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: I tried this version but still leaves null the dates and this error comes up : ER_UNKNOWN_SYSTEM_VARIABLE: Unknown system variable 'FECHA_POSICION'

Comment: try it with backticks see changed answer else you have to show me the table with a CREATE  TABLE as text

Comment: I updated it with the create table see if there is the error! Backticks didnt work but thanks!!

Comment: i tested this with MySQL 8.0.25 this works without a problem, float and comma separated numbers at least didn't work i had to switch to decimal and dots

Comment: It is maybe because I have the mysql 5.6.31 version?

Comment: shouldn't  nothing was made in that regard, try to rename the columns to a in small letters but your version is out of date.

Comment: @JosepHHH Also the is a 5.6.51 Version already available, see if an update helps